# When were negative numbers fully accepted into mathematics?

Tags: math-history, foundations

Dedekind gave a construction and explanation of integers and rational in 1858. This was as ordered pairs of natural numbers. I'm not sure if this was the standard view of these objects after this point.

If there can be no conclusive "when", are there any textbooks that include general constructions or something like this?

When did integers start being viewed as a ring structure?

I've gotten side tracked a lot lately with math history, but I think this is what I am most concerned about. I find Dedekind's work to be interesting though.

Thank you.

Comment: Better asked on the math history stackexchange.

Comment: Your question on this topic over at the hsm.stackexchange site got some useful comments. I would suggest following up on those comments over at that site.

Comment: Euler has introduced and finished with them by page 5 of his algebra, mid to late 1700s

Comment: Negative numbers predate modern mathematics and their rejection was isolated to certain Europeans but not a general phenomenon.  "Nine Chapters on the Mathematical Art" by Liu Hui provides their algebraic structure nearly 1000 years before algebra was invented and that knowledge was known to the first algebrists. I doubt you'll find any modern treatment of them that doesn't have ancient roots.

Comment: @RobinSparrow it is not a formal treatment, he is still attached to the concept of numbers having to be associated with "quantity" hence his analogy with "debt". It is not a formal treatment, and hence, other mathematicians of his time refused to accept them.

Comment: @CyclotomicField ... Enter Dedekind...

Comment: Indian mathematicians adopted base ten positional notation and adopted zero as another number around the year 600. They also introduced negative magnitudes in the commercial context to manage debts and, in that case, positive numbers implied capital assets. Brahmagupta (598-688), around the year 628, knew the rule of signs for the product. (suite)

Comment: In Europe, negative numbers were introduced by Leonardo of Pisa in his Liber Abaci (1202), but were not accepted (as numbers) until the end of the 18th century. G. Cardano (1501-1576) called the negative solutions of equations impossible values and considered them symbols without real meaning in the problem he was trying to solve. R. Descartes (1596-1650) called the negative roots of equations false and B. Pascal (1623-1662) considered it absurd to subtract a positive quantity from zero.

Comment: @Demon the first formal treatment is "Nine Chapters on the Mathematical Art" by Liu Hui. It predates Dedekind by millenia. You seem to have a fundamental misunderstand of when negative numbers were accepted and used. We had tables of debts and credits dating back over 7000 years from ancient Mesopotamia. The idea of negative numbers is as old as writing itself.

Comment: @Demon my point is Euler considered them so unremarkable in their essence, in the mid-1700s that he was done in about 2 pages talking about what they meant. It boiled down to "the numbers we need to add and have less", which is exactly what the formalizations formalized. As others are saying, the ideas have been clear for a long time, though formalizations were lacking. I'm neither a historian nor a mathematician, just giving some context of what textbooks include around that time.

Comment: @ Demon that’s right. Many of us here have constructed number systems following Dedekind, von Neumann etc.